# Не находится файл

Tags: python

столкнулся с такой ошибкой при выводе музыки, вроде как пишет что файл не найден хотя всё проверил, файл в mp3 и прямо в папке. Посмотрите пожалуйста, что может быть не так.

```
def soundPlay(soundName):
sound = pyglet.media.load(soundName, streaming=False)
sound.play()
pyglet.app.run()

soundPlay("sound/workStart.mp3")

log {
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:/Users/___/Desktop/___/___/___/main.py", line 52, in <module>
   workTimer(0, "Началась работа", "sound/workStart.mp3")

   File "c:/Users/___/Desktop/___/___/___/main.py", line 36, in workTimer
   soundPlay(soundName)

   File "c:/Users/___/Desktop/___/___/___/main.py", line 9, in soundPlay
   sound = pyglet.media.load(soundName, streaming=False)

   File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py",
   line 130, in load

   loaded_source = decoder.decode(file, filename, streaming)

   File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs 
   \wave.py", line 109, in decode

   return StaticSource(WaveSource(filename, file))

   File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs
   \wave.py", line 53, in __init__

   file = open(filename, 'rb')

   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sound/workStart.mp3'
}
```

Comment: В названии юзера есть кирилица?

Comment: Прямо в папке какой? А скрипт в какой?

Comment: Используйте `pathlib`

Comment: А лучше pathlib2

Comment: @Namerek вы про [это](https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/pathlib2)? Тут вроде 3 питон

Comment: Как вы запускаете скрипт?

Comment: Создал функцию soundPlay, и из другой функций вызываю её передав параметр с путём до файла mp3.

Comment: soundPlay("sound/workStart.mp3")

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
CURRDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
def soundPlay(soundName):
    sound = pyglet.media.load(soundName, streaming=False)
    sound.play()
    pyglet.app.run()
    soundPlay(f"{CURRDIR}sound/workStart.mp3")
```

Comment: Только вызов функции должно быть за её пределами :)